# How can I change my makefile to redirect .o

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to change my makefile to redirect the .o to a lib folder (and have the .c in a src folder). I would also like the executables to be at the same level as the makefile.

As for the .h, I have no idea where to put it!

```
CC = gcc
    CFLAGS = -std=c11 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Werror -fPIC -pthread -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -fstack-protector
LDLIBS = -lrt
RM = rm -f
ARFLAGS = rs

all: server client info_proc info_user

server: server.o header.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

server.o: server.c header.h
    gcc -c server.c

client: client.o header.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

client.o: client.c header.h

header.o: header.c header.h
    gcc -c header.c

info_proc: info_proc.o

info_proc.o: info_proc.c
    gcc -c info_proc.c

info_user: info_user.o

info_user.o: info_user.c
    gcc -c info_user.c

rmpipe:
    $(RM) question_pipe

clean:
    $(RM) server client info_proc info_user question_pipe *.o *~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
all: main

main: lib/a.o lib/b.o lib/main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

lib/a.o: a.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

lib/b.o: b.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

lib/main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Or instead of writing your own `Makefile` you could use one of these build
tools:

- [GNU Autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html)
- [Cmake](https://cmake.org/)
- [SCons](http://scons.org/)

which on the long run are much easier to maintain than a self-written
`Makefile`.